# Difference between dtrtrs and dtrsm

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, blas

I am looking for some triangular solvers, and I have come across two solvers. One in BLAS: [dtrsm](http://www.netlib.org/blas/dtrsm.f)  and another in LAPACK: [dtrtrs](http://www.netlib.org/clapack/CLAPACK-3.1.1/SRC/dtrtrs.c). From the looks of it both seem to have common functionality, with dtrsm having a little bit more functionality (scaling the right hand side before solving the system).

I would like to know
1) How else do these functions differ ?
2) When performing the same operation, which is faster ?
3) If the answer to (2) is not obvious, When is dtrsm suggested over dtrtrs and vice versa ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Besides scaling, `dtrsm` can also solve systems in which the triangular matrix is right-multiplied into the unknown matrix (i.e., it can solve XA = B as well as AX = B).  On the other hand, `dtrsm` can silently fail if A is singular, whereas `dtrtrs` checks for this condition and reports an error.
2. In a "typical" LAPACK distribution, `dtrtrs` is just a wrapper that checks for singularity and then calls `dtrsm`.  `dtrsm` is therefore *slightly* faster, but that difference is insignificant for matrices of any reasonable size.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to be working on GPUs. This saved me a lot of time and spared me from shooting in the dark until I figured it out.